# Armory 0.93 on Testnet: consistent unconfirmed Txs sent from connected Bitcoin-cli (log attached)

Tags: testnet, armory

Running Armory (0.93.0.82) on Win7 x64 with the following flags:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Armory\ArmoryQt.exe" --testnet --datadir=d:\data\armory\testnet3 --satoshi-datadir="d:\data\bitcoincore" --rpcport=8332 --debug --netlog --mtdebug --logfile=d:\data\armory`

You'll find [the log file](https://gist.github.com/eb868e035200bb7c2d79) throws a recurring error...

```
    -WARN  - 1427685617: (..\Blockchain.cpp:47) Somehow tried to add header that's already in map
    -WARN  - 1427685617: (..\Blockchain.cpp:48)     Header Hash: 00000000ad4e4c886567776c89e752614f251cca28b7dfcaf16867677ba0245a
```

FYI, those times/blocks correspond to the most recent blocks, as validated by Bitcoin-CLI.

It's worth noting that the "current block" field in Armory shows a block ~6000 old (stuck on `323060`), and mouse hover says *"last block received 1.5 minutes ago"* (or something similar) and updates with the block discovery.

Bitcoincore (v0.10 btw) [gives this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycajw.jpg) (the top 2 Txs - [TxID 706b60a90510e8db0186be5980819931127110e300ce10c5a5b3f5fb04667dc2](http://test.webbtc.com/tx/706b60a90510e8db0186be5980819931127110e300ce10c5a5b3f5fb04667dc2) - are labelled `?` however they are confirmed in Bitcoincore eventually)

I've tried numerous wallets instances in Armory, updating, ensuring the client is connected, using the rescanning/rebuilding database option, etc. *EDIT: Rescanning the database has actually erased all record of the Txs in Armory*

What is wrong here?

Comment: This seems like it might be a question better suited for Armory developers, maybe you should file an issue here: https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved this by numerous trial and error CMDs. The problem lay in the Armory implementation, specifically, the `--datadir` flag.

The **working** CLI flags:

- **ARMORY:** `-qt.exe --testnet --datadir=d:\data\armory\testnet3 --satoshi-datadir=d:\data\bitcoincore --rpcport=8332`
- **BITCOIN-QT:** `bitcoin-qt.exe -datadir="d:\data\bitcoincore" -testnet -rpcport=8332`

Contradicting Armory's FAQ (in the FAQ itself) is the requirement to explicitly identify the *testnet**3*** directory for the `--data-dir` flag (`--data-dir==SOME\DIR\Armory\testnet3`). If the testnet3 directory isn't identified, Armory confuses the mainnet blockchain data with the testnet chain data.

The `bitcoin.conf` contents were:

```
listen=1
daemon=1
server=1
rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
rpcport=8332
```